# Send local notifications on specific days every week?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to setup local notifications so it only notify the user with a notification only on friday and saturday and sunday?

Comment: What you could do I think is every time the user opens the app, calculate how much time there is until Friday, Saturday and Sunday and set 3 notifications up. The next time they open just clear those notifications and then reset them up.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only schedule `UILocalNotification`s with a `fireDate`, which is the time from now until firing the notification.

Comment: But that makes the fireDate relevant to the date the user register fot the notification?

Comment: Please explain what you mean? The `fireDate` are simply the seconds which have to elapse from now to the time the notification should fire.

Comment: Sorry i meant relative and not relevant.

Comment: the `fireDate` is in epoch time (also often called unix time).